# Displaying text on top of text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display text on top of the  text with bootstrap4

My HTML looks like this

```
<div class="d-lg-flex align-items-lg-start intro-heading text-uppercase">
   <span class="text-black-50 d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(2px);margin: 0px;">
  INTRODUCTION</span>
  <span class="text-white d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(0px);color: #ffffff;">INTRODUCTION</span>
</div>
```

I would like the text to not be side by side but to display on top of the other text if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you would need to use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your wrapper, `position: relative`. And second span `position: absolute` and `left: 0`.

```
<div class="d-lg-flex align-items-lg-start intro-heading text-uppercase" style="position: relative">
   <span class="text-black-50 d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(2px);margin: 0px;">
  INTRODUCTION</span>
  <span class="text-white d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(0px);color: #ffffff; position: absolute; left: 0">INTRODUCTION</span>
</div>
```

Your wrapper has to be relative, because then all its absolute children will use it as bounds.

And I would highly recommend against using inline styles, but rather give your elements classes, and then write css in external file. It has quite few advatages as maintainability, reusability, it can be cached by browser, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pseudo elements`. I presume this is what you needed

```css
.wrapper {
  background: grey;
}

.text-black-50:before {
  filter: blur(2px);
  margin: 0px;
  content: 'INTRODUCTION';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.text-black-50 {
  width: 749px;
  filter: blur(0px);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-lg-flex wrapper align-items-lg-start intro-heading text-uppercase">
  <span class="text-black-50 d-inline float-none">
  INTRODUCTION</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While lukas answer is correct, the intended way to add a blurred shadow to some text is to add the css proprety `text-shadow` to your second span.

```html
<span class="text-white d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;color: #ffffff;text-shadow: 0 0 4px #222;">INTRODUCTION</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
  <span class="text-white d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(0px);color: #00000;">Whatever your text is</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d-lg-flex align-items-lg-start intro-heading text-uppercase">
   <span class="text-black-50 d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(2px);margin: 0px;">
  INTRODUCTION</span>
<span class="text-white d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(0px);color: #ffff;">INTRODUCTION</span>
</div>
 <br>
<div>
  <span class="text-white d-inline float-none" style="width:749px;filter: blur(0px);color: #00000;">Whatever your text is</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them, then set the one you want to be on top  `position:absolute;` and then set its `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` values to adjust it to exactly where you want. In addition you might consider `z-index` too to specify which should be on top.